# Model.Find() - How to return array of ObjectId

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have an array of category titles. I want to make function return an array of `ObjectId` from these titles. How can I do it?

```
Category Model: {_id, title}


    const findCategoryIdsFromCategoryTitles = (titles) => {
        return Category.find({ title: { $in: titles } })._id
    }

    let titles = ["A1", "A2", "A3"]
    let categoryIds = findCategoryIdsFromCategoryTitles(titles)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongoose .select() method to select specific field.

```
const findCategoryIdsFromCategoryTitles = (titles) => {
    return Category.find({ title: { $in: titles } }).select('_id'); // Here you are selecting only _id field
}
```

Comment: How I can return an array with Id string, like: [ "5d2e8ea173d1914ddee9443e",  "5d2e8ea173d1914ddee94431" ], not an object array [ { _id: 5d2e8ea173d1914ddee9443e } , { _id: 5d2e8ea173d1914ddee94431 }] ?

Answer (score 0):

First solution : [select](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

```
const findCategoryIdsFromCategoryTitles = (titles) => {
    return Category.find({ title: { $in: titles } }).select({ "_id": 1}); // or select("_id")
}

let titles = ["A1", "A2", "A3"]
let categoryIds = findCategoryIdsFromCategoryTitles(titles)
```

Second solution with  [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html)

```
const findCategoryIdsFromCategoryTitles = (titles) => {
    return Category.aggregate([{$match: {title: {$in: titles}}}, {$project: {_id: 1}}])
}

let titles = ["A1", "A2", "A3"]
let categoryIds = findCategoryIdsFromCategoryTitles(titles)
```

to have a array ids :

```
const findCategoryIdsFromCategoryTitles = async (titles) => {
    return await Category.find({ title: { $in: titles } }).select({ "_id": 1}); // or select("_id")
}
let categoryIds = await findCategoryIdsFromCategoryTitles(titles)
const result  = categoryIds.map(({_id})=>_id)
```

```js
const result = [ { _id: '5d2e8ea173d1914ddee9443e' } , { _id: '5d2e8ea173d1914ddee94431' }].map(({_id})=>_id);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! How I can return an array with Id string, like: [ "5d2e8ea173d1914ddee9443e", "5d2e8ea173d1914ddee94431" ], not an object array [ { _id: 5d2e8ea173d1914ddee9443e } , { _id: 5d2e8ea173d1914ddee94431 }] ?

Comment: @NguyenVanTuan use  .map(({_id})=>_id)